# Running ntpdate as non root user

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, root, ntp

I am trying to write a code that will listen to messages, and will force ntp sync (using ntpdate command) each time it gets a message.

The code is written in c++, on Ubuntu 14.04, and runs OK. But the system command fails each time, because it does not have root privileges.

This code suppose to start automatically when the system boots up, so I can't just run the executable with "sudo". 
After searching the internet, the only solution I found was to log in as root user, but this will compromise security.

I know the ntp daemon process runs with root privileges, but I am not sure how it is implemented.

*Do you know of any way I can run c++ code with root privileges without compromising security?*

Comment: Write a daemon and let it run on startup, it will run with root privileges by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The NTP daemon runs with root privileges because it is started under the root account.
- Generally, programs which run as daemons are started under the root account; some of them drop root privileges voluntarily by calling [`setuid()`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man3/setuid.3posix.html), [`seteuid()`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man3/seteuid.3posix.html), etc.
- You can always make a dedicated account for the program and run it under that account,

  - either by making it setuid to that account,
  - or by using [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/sudo.8.html)`-u`,
  - or, if you start your daemon from a `systemd` unit file, by specifying [`user=` and `group=`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676007/how-do-i-make-my-systemd-service-run-via-specific-user-and-start-on-boot) in the unit description file.

  You can then edit the [`/etc/sudoers`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) to allow that account to run `ntpdate` and only `ntpdate` as root without a password.